# How to have HTML/JS on a Jenkins build configuration page?

Tags: jenkins, continuous-integration, continuous-deployment

I am trying to run some AJAX on the frontend of a Jenkins build configuration page. To be exact to have a dropdown selection of available databases on a remote server. How do I accomplish this?

Answer (score 0):

In case you need a dynamic list you can use Active Choice Parameter and add a groovy script to generate dynamic list from a remote api call.

below is an example i use to generate list of vpc's from aws :

```
#!groovy
def sout = new StringBuffer(), serr = new StringBuffer()

def process = [ "aws", "ec2", "describe-vpcs", "--query", "Vpcs[*].[Tags[?Key==`Name`].Value]"].execute()
process.consumeProcessOutput(sout, serr)
process.waitFor();
def s3_vpcs = sout.tokenize('\n')

def vpcs = []
for ( vpc in s3_vpcs) {
    vpcs.add(vpc) 
}

return vpcs
```